# Select only the ids using Specification and Pageable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am looking to select only the ids using this approach. Not sure how to get only the ids of matching employees.

```
Page<Employee> findAll(Specification<Employee> specification, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Use a projection instead of the full entity.

Comment: @M.Deinum do we need to use any custom repository or can use standard approach? If you can show in detail will be helpful

Comment: The documentation explains this in quite enough detail. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1033